# Images being overwritten

Tags: php, image

In 1 of my **upload-image1.php** I got this code down here but I think I am missing something because when I upload the same image twice it will just overwrite the image it doesnt rename it. Is there a peace of code that I can add to prevent this. And if there is another file that you guys need to look at let me know and I will post it. Its from the WordPress theme that uses custom upload.

```
<?php 
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
$uploaddir = './uploads/image/small_image/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image1']['name']); 
$raw_file_name= $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
if ($width==80 && $height==80) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
        echo "success";
    } 
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
else {
    echo "size_error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` is expected to overwrite existing file: [PHP Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) (see the warning part).

If you want to prevent it, add something to the file name:

```
$file = $uploaddir.time()."_".basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);
```

Of course you can replace `time()` with many other options: upload user id, `date("Ymd_His")`,etc.

Comment: @baychaser Glad to be of help!:)